# Can we process media files like images,videos via Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-blob-storage

We are trying to ingest data to Azure blobs.

Thing is the ingestion data is in the continuous format, that means we are going to receive them on continuous basis.
The content is kind of creatives like - images, videos, audios etc.

We would like to ingest them to Azure blobs. Initially we thought of Event Hubs but as per our understandings they are useful in case there is structured/semi-structured data. Creatives are nothing but unstructured. Is it possible to load them using Event Hubs?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're able to fit your binary-encoded data into an Event Hubs message (I believe 1MB max event size), you will not be able to stream such content through Event Hubs. Large media is really not a good fit for such messages.

Now, if the binary content (videos, images, etc as you mentioned) were uploaded / stored somewhere else (e.g. blob storage, or storage in another service), you can embed the *link* to such content within a given Event Hubs message, and then when processing that message, retrieve said binary content and store it in the appropriate place (e.g. specific blob in specific storage account).